# Convert Win Form Text input to a variable being used in PowerShell

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have built a WinForms GUI to make PowerShell easier.

```
function CalendarShare {
    Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $FromUser:\calendar -User $ToUser -AccessRights FolderOwner
}
```

`$FromUser` is a WinForms text input, which needs to work within the function to share the calendar.

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'User'. Cannot convert the
"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: *@*.co.uk" value of type
"Deserialized.System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.MailboxFolderUserIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-MailboxFolderPermission], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Add-MailboxFolderPermission
    + PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com
```

Comment: @I.TDelinquent - The issue is sharing the specific folder (Calendar), not the whole email account

Comment: What issues or errors are you getting? Are you correct in using $FromUser instead of $FromUser.Text?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent I have put a comment with the error that is generated. I am using a win form text box for the email input, $FromUser.text:\calendar is being used to share the calendar

Comment: This is the same issue that you had earlier, you aren't getting the Text property on the textbox. Try using $FromUser.Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is caused by the way you use the variable. When using : right after a variable, PowerShell interprets it as a variable reference. You might have seen this when using the $env variable. If not, try to run `$env:computername`

If you change your script to something like this:

```
function CalendarShare {
    $From = '{0}:/calendar' -f $fromUser
    Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $From -User $ToUser -AccessRights FolderOwner
}
```

you might have more success. That is of course, if all other prerequisites for the Add-MailboxFolderPermission is in place, your $fromUser contains a valid user string and the To user contains a valid userid.

You might want to consider making a proper function with proper parameters like this:

```
function Add-CalendarShare {
param (
    $FromUser,
    $ToUser
    )
    $from = '{0}:/calendar' -f $FromUser
    Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $from -User $ToUser -AccessRights FolderOwner
}
```

and then run the code n your Win form like this `Add-CalendarShare -FromUser UserID@domain.com -ToUser userToAdd@domain.com`

That will get you started with a more PowerShellish syntag and there are endless ways to elaborate from there. Especially the CmdletBinding will blow your mind ;-)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-6

Comment: If your $fromUser has System.Windows.Forms.TextBox as typename, you need to extract the text. That can be done by running ```Add-CalendarShare -FromUser $FromUser.Text -ToUser $ToUser.Text

Comment: How Would I look at implementing the :\calendar? Is it worth me creating a variable called $Calendar. $Calendar = ':\calendar. Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $from $Calendar -USer etc.

Comment: If you use the code provided, the ```:\calender``` bit will already be in the $from variable

Comment: It doesnt like the variable and the :\calendar. I will have another go at work in the morning, and report if the issue reoccurs.

Comment: You can add a ```Write-Verbose $from -Verbose``` on the line right after ```$from = '{0}:/calendar' -f $FromUser```. Then you will know if the string is property formatted.

Comment: Done as you said. Result 'Cannot bind argument to parameter 'User' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-MailboxFolderPermission], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Add-MailboxFolderPermission
    + PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com
'

Comment: Issue has been resolved. I converted $ToUser input into $ var = ToUser.text, then used $VAR in the powershell command